# "Google will share your name, email address..." message in Google SignIn account selection screen even if app not requests these fields

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, google-signin

I used below options for Google SignIn feature. The account selection shows that Google will share user's **name** and **email** event if my app only requires `JWT` to authenticate with server.

```
private val options by lazy {
    GoogleSignInOptions.Builder()
                       .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                       .build()
}
```

[Account selection screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0jTc.png)

Actually, the returned `JWT` payload doesn't contains name and email address.

```
{
    "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
    "azp": "305161181161-lu040ujhsg99ud8oki8gvej4i20n4XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "aud": "305161181161-k4isep20r73s5cio200io5e2u44dnXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "sub": "112520390335353388XXX",
    "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgTHkBQ3z_L7uxYSNBLbVlSMjOU-8OVrrwQ6-uHUw=s9XXX",
    "iat": 1609249XXX,
    "exp": 1609252XXX
}
```

Are there any configs in `SDK` or google console to hide "Google will share your name, email address..." message?